# SearchView.OnQueryTextListner always returning original list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I am trying to implement the SearchView within the toolbar. When I try to search my list the original list is always being returned not the new list while trying to do the search.

When I debug it starts to show the new list with the correct amount of items inside of it, but then when its done it just returns the original list size.

When debugging it goes into the publicResults but then doesn't update the adapter. Not sure why it gets the new list but not replace the old one.

Activity that implements the SearchView

```
public class LoadsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    @Inject
    Lazy<IMyLoadsRetroService> retroService;

    @Inject
    IUser user;

    public LoadsActivity() {
        Injector.INSTANCE.getViewComponent(this).inject(this);
    }


    public static void startLoadsActivity(Context context) {
        Intent loadsIntent = new Intent(context, LoadsActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(loadsIntent);
    }

    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.loadProgressBar)
    ProgressBar loadProgressBar;
    @BindView(R.id.fab)
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    LoadAdapter loadAdapter;
    private List<IMyLoadSummary> myLoadSummaryList = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loads);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        loadAdapter = new LoadAdapter(this, myLoadSummaryList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(loadAdapter);

        loadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.startLoadsActivity(LoadsActivity.this);
            }
        });


        retroService.get().getMyLoads().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<MyLoadSummary>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        loadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Toaster.s(LoadsActivity.this, e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<MyLoadSummary> myLoadSummaries) {
                        loadAdapter.setLoadData(myLoadSummaries);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_search) {


            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //leaving blank to disable back button
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        loadAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Adapter with the Filter

```
public class LoadAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LoadAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<? extends IMyLoadSummary> originalList;
    private List<? extends IMyLoadSummary> filteredList;

    public LoadAdapter(Context context, List<IMyLoadSummary> list) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.originalList = list;
        this.filteredList = list;

        getFilter();
    }

    public void setLoadData(List<? extends IMyLoadSummary> mLoadData) {
        originalList = mLoadData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Gson gson = GsonFactory.getDefault();
        String jsonListString = gson.toJson(originalList.get(position));
        holder.loadsTextView.setText(jsonListString);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return originalList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filteredResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                    ArrayList<IMyLoadSummary> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

                    //search content for any number...hopefully
                    for (IMyLoadSummary myLoadSummary : originalList) {
                        if (Integer.toString(myLoadSummary.getNumber()).contains(constraint.toString())) {
                            tempList.add(myLoadSummary);
                        }
                    }
                    filteredResults.count = tempList.size();
                    filteredResults.values = tempList;
                } else {
                    filteredResults.count = originalList.size();
                    filteredResults.values = originalList;
                }

                return filteredResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                filteredList = (List<? extends IMyLoadSummary>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView loadsTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            loadsTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.loadJSONText);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what i want to suggest is just save the data into android sqlite then run the select * from table_name where name like '%string%"'; query and display it in listview .hope it helps you it is a simple way to do search and fastest too